# Using jQuery validate with HTML5 email input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a `<input type="email">` using the jQuery validate plugin and the actual validation works fine, but it appears that if incorrect value has been entered and an error message appears, the error message remains after the error has been corrected.

Am I doing something wrong or does the validate plugin simply not support `type="email"` inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation plugin can't handle input type of email yet.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, jQuery validation is lazy. It won't validate until you try to submit the form. Or call the `isValid()` method. Once it has done a validation though, it will become eager: It will validate every field as soon as the field loses focus.

On another note: Shouldn't that be `class="email"`? No too sure about it though, just a comment (which I can't do yet).

You might want to slap some code in here, so we can see what it's actually doing.

Comment: HTML5 forms support a new type of email for an input element and do their own built in validation (not very good at that) for emails. Even if you add the "email" class to the element, the validation plugin won't work with it yet.

Comment: @user156629 Ah, I was under the impression he was just using a 'text' input to get an email. Because you can use class="email" on that. That's where my confusion came from, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give `<input class="email"/>`

Comment: i am talking about < input type=email> in html 5